# bitmap overflowing page on print

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, printing, bitmap, syncfusion

I'm trying to print a windows form.  When the form is maximized the image runs over the page.  i'm able to Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal right before printing but I know this is not the best way.  Is there a better way to "fit to page", since the user can change the form size?

```
Private Sub PrintToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PrintToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim ppd As PrintPreviewDialog = New PrintPreviewDialog()

    ppd.Document = New Printing.PrintDocument()

    AddHandler ppd.Document.PrintPage, AddressOf Document_PrintPage
    ppd.Document.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True

    ppd.ShowDialog()
End Sub
Private Sub Document_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)

    Dim bt As Bitmap = New Bitmap(Me.Width, Me.Height)

    Me.DrawToBitmap(bt, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.Width, Me.Height))

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bt, 0, 0)
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work better in case anyone has the same problem.

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(bt, 0, 0, e.PageBounds.Width, e.PageBounds.Height)
```